# Spin.js - Disabling element when loading

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, spin.js

I am wanting to use the spin.js library when users are performing actions on my site but i am not seeing how or if it is possible to disable the element the spinner is on top of. for example, when my grid is loading i do not want the user clicking on anywhere on the grid itself.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Spin.js is just an animated spinning animation. If you want to turn off everything else "behind it" I assume it is in a modal window, in which case you just need a 100% width and height div that has a z-index higher then that of every other element with the spinner on it.

So something like

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:9999;">
SPIN STUFF with z-index 10000;
</div>
```

That would cover every element and prevent them from clicking on it.

If I read your question wrong let me know.

Comment: Yes, i knew it was only mean for displaying animation but its being heavily utilized from what ive read in ajax scenarios, so my requirement seems very common. i'll give that a try, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Steven's answer works to disable the page - however, I found that if I used that method, the other elements on the page remained blocked and could not be clicked on. You could get around it with hiding and showing the element as desired - however, when I did that I found that the SpinJS spinner stopped centring and ended up in the top-left corner.

In the end, I combined SpinJS with [the JQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/), which puts an overlay over the page temporarily and prevents any clicking, with some customisable options.

So in the end, my code looks something like...

```
var target = document.getElementById("centre");
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
$.blockUI({ message: null, overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#ddd' } });

//Things things things  

spinner.stop();
$.unblockUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added block UI to spin.js, It uses the bootstrap css because that's what I use but you can adapt it to your own needs.

[spin.backdrop](https://github.com/weisssean/spin.backdrop)